# Get the warning Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/octet-stream when using window.open(<url>,'_self)

Tags: javascript, json, windows, url, download

I am using window.open() to open a document URL being sent to me. This url is dynamic. This gives me the warning "Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/octet-stream." How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This warning shows you that URL you are aproaching is in fact not an HTML document that can be interpreted as webpage, but some kind of unknown downloadable file.

Such target cannot be interpreted by your browser as fully functional web page, and it causes the warning

Comment: Okay, but it downloads it anyway. So it knows what it's supposed to do. How to let it know it won't be a page. Again since it already knows the file is a zip.